# two types of directory separators in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

while debugging in `JPath::find`, my `$path` variable attain a value which is a mixture of directory separators. Half are back slashes and half are forward slashes. why is this so??

```
C:\Users\arslan\Desktop\xampp-win32-1.8.1-VC9\xampp\htdocs\COM/components/com_hello/views/pendingHello/tmpl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses back slashes `\` and linux/mac (all unix based) use forward slashes `/` for the directory separator normally. Within PHP, either one actually works, as well as a mix like you see.

There is a constant in PHP called `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` which has the correct slash for your OS. However, when creating a path this isn't typically necessary, because Windows will still process what you have correctly.

So, the short answer is that `/` is used within the component which works fine no matter where Joomla is installed; however the first part of the path is system generated and Windows will always generate the path with `\`.

You can see a bit more on this here: http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary

Comment: thanks David. your answers are always to the point and dense, . .  and also let the questioner to learn 10 times more than his expectations.